# How to determine what was the source of the creation of the transaction (API, CONTROL_PANEL, RECURRING)?

Tags: braintree

In StatusHistory field of Transaction object there is a Source field in each element of the collection. However, the value of this field is always the same (RECURRING) - no matter what was the cause of the creation of the transaction. 
How can I filter out transactions generated automatically at subcription renew from collection of all subscriptions transactions?

Comment: Because you want to filter out all the transactions created by renewal, are you looking for just the starting transaction from a subscription?

Comment: I'm looking for all the transactions for a given subscription that were created by renewal and not for example by proration on upgrade.

Comment: I work for Braintree, and I'd recommend reaching out to support at: support@braintreepayments.com as they're able to answer more specific questions.